# Express.js UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

So I have the following code:

```
app.post('/api/login', async function (req, res){
  try  {
    let [sorted,users] = await getSorted();
    const pw = req.body.password;
    const submittedUser = req.body.username;
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    // const user = { id: req.body.id, username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password };
    // USERNAME = FIRSTNAME
    var user = new User({firstname: req.body.username, eMail: req.body.eMail, password: hashedPassword });
    sorted.forEach(async ([firstname, password]) => {
      let result = bcrypt.compareSync(pw, password);
      // r = true if hash = hashed pw
      var serializeCookie = function(key, value, hrs) {
        // This is res.cookie’s code without the array management and also ignores signed cookies.
        if ('number' == typeof value) value = val.toString();
        if ('object' == typeof value) value = JSON.stringify(val);
        return cookie.serialize(key, value, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * hrs), httpOnly: true });
      }; 

      var setMultipleCookies = function(res) {
        set_cookies.push(getCookie(access_token, myValue1.toString(), default_cookie_age));
        set_cookies.push(getCookie(loggedinid, myValue2.toString(), default_cookie_age));
        res.header("Set-Cookie", set_cookies);
      } 
      set_cookies = ['loggedinid', id]
      if (result === true && firstname == submittedUser) {
        jwt2.sign({user}, 'secrethere', { expiresIn: '15min'}, (err, token) =>{
          set_cookies.push('access_token'+ 'Bearer'+token).header("Set-Cookie", set_cookies)
                     .json(user);
        });
      }
      else {
        res.status(200).send("bad login");
      } 
    });    
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send();
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Error I am getting thrown out:

```
(node:6628) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6628) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

What I am trying to accomplish:

My login function, which definitely worked before needed some pimping in order to set multiple cookies. I found a question here on SO, which I can't find anymore, which stated that there's a bug and some comments that maybe it's fixed, but found no evidence of that since the code just did not work. So I had to do this hack, which I implemented in my code and it gave me these errors.
`set_cookies = ['loggedinid', id]` should get the second cookie as key loggedinid and value variable id. Id is the MongoDB ID name

Comment: Assuming `sorted` is an array, any errors thrown from the async callback to `sorted.forEach` (`async ([firstname, password]) => {...}`) won't be caught in the `catch` block. Try doing `await Promise.all(sorted.map(async ([firstname, password]) => {...}))`, which maps each item to a promise, and then waits for all the promises to resolve.

Comment: @cherryblossom still getting `(node:352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:352) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejection...` :/

Comment: and also `(node:352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: id is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least these issues:

1. There is no `await` anywhere in the `forEach` callback, so marking that callback as `async` has no purpose. Drop that keyword, and you'll not get that unhandled promise rejection any more. Change:

   ```
   sorted.forEach(async ([firstname, password]) => {
   ```

   To:

   ```
   sorted.forEach(([firstname, password]) => {
   ```
2. The following statement references an non-existing `header` property:

   ```
   set_cookies.push('access_token'+ 'Bearer'+token).header("Set-Cookie", set_cookies)
              .json(user);
   ```

   The return value of `push` is an integer, so you cannot call `.header()` on that. That triggers an exception. Maybe you intended to call `.header()` on `res`:

   ```
   set_cookies.push('access_token'+ 'Bearer'+token);
   res.header("Set-Cookie", set_cookies)
      .json(user);
   ```
3. You have an undefined variable `id` in this line:

   ```
   set_cookies = ['loggedinid', id]
   ```

   I cannot really say what you intended here, but you should make sure that `id` has been defined and has the appropriate value
4. The variable `val` in `serializeCookie` is never defined. Possibly you intended `value`.

There are still other issues unrelated to your question, such as:

1. The two functions `serializeCookie` and `setMultipleCookies` are never called.
2. If you do intend to use `serializeCookie`, then it is quite inconsistent in how it writes data. There really should not be any type-checking `if` there. It should just *always* do:

   ```
   value = JSON.stringify(value);
   ```

   The function could just be:

   ```
   var serializeCookie = function(key, value, hrs) {
       return cookie.serialize(key, JSON.stringify(value), 
              { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * hrs), httpOnly: true });
   };
   ```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong... I followed the advice from cherryblossom and then followed your advice and I seem to be getting the same error...

Comment: Did you remove `async`?

Comment: Just did from `sorted.map(([firstname, password...`. Give me a second to test.

Comment: I don't see a `sorted.map` in your question's code. This is confusing.

Comment: I followed the advice from cherryblossom in the question comments, hence there is that in the code. Should I revert to my previous code?

Comment: My answer is replying to the code in your question, not to other code. See third point I added to my answer as well.

Comment: Your solution works, but now the cookie only works on Firefox and is a long string without spaces in the value field with the data and the other cookie with id is missing... Any clue how to solve this? I already upvoted your answer

Comment: Well, that is an entirely different question. You are passing an array to `header("Set-Cookie", )`, but that array should have strings in the cookie format. As this is unrelated to your uncaught promise rejection problem, please investigate this yourself, and if you cannot make it work, as a new question about it.